# Delete Data in Multiple Table with the same id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This is the Query:

```
DELETE FROM patientpersonal,patientmedical,patientdental
WHERE patientpersonal.'" & dpatientid & "' = patientmedical.'" & 
    dpatientid & "' AND patientpersonal.'" & dpatientid & "' = patientdental.'"  
    & dpatientid & "'
```

It has a error of MySQL 1064

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems like you would want to wrap three statements into one stored procedure.  You could pass in the ID as a parameter into the stored procedure and then run the three delete statements.  It will be simple and it can be transactional so that you can ensure that it does not partially execute.

Here is a good starter link to MySQL stored procedures if you need it:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

I wasn't able to test this so it might be a bit off, but your stored procedure should look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sprocDeleteAllInfo(IN my_id INT)
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM patientpersonal WHERE patientid = my_id;
DELETE FROM patientmedical WHERE patientid = my_id;
DELETE FROM patientdental WHERE patientid = my_id;

COMMIT;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete from each of the tables individually.

```
DELETE FROM patientpersonal WHERE patientid = ?
DELETE FROM patientmedical WHERE patientid = ?
DELETE FROM patientdental WHERE patientid = ?
```

OR you could just set a foreign key to `ON DELETE CASCADE` for your patients table if that is what you wanted.